# print all attributes in a xml by recursive method

Tags: recursion, dom4j

The problem is why I can't find any attributes from the rootElement?

my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="GBK"?>

<AccountInfos>
  <!--this is a test for dom4j-->
  <AccountInfo1 WebsiteName="ÐÂÀË" Account="123">Account1</AccountInfo1>
  <AccountInfo2 WebsiteName="ÍøÒ×" Account="123">Account2</AccountInfo2>
</AccountInfos>
```

and my code is like this

```
    private void treeWalker(Element element)
{
    int size = element.nodeCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Node node = element.node(i);
        if (node instanceof Element)
        {
            treeWalker((Element) node);
        }
        else if(node instanceof Attribute)
        {
            Attribute attribute=(Attribute)node;
            System.out.println(attribute.getName()+":"+attribute.getValue());
        }
        else 
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

when I debug in this method I can‘t go into the second if block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are not considered part of the Element (or Branch, actually) content (such as Elements, Comments or Text nodes). You must retrieve then specially, e.g. with an attributeIterator().